# Toggle disable/enable checkbox by replacing class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, toggleclass

I have a set of 5 checkboxes with class set to "child". I want that if I select one checkbox, rest of them goes disabled. I have tried following code but it disables the all checkboxes.

```
if ( !$(this).is ( ":checked" ) ) {
  $(this).removeClass().addClass("hand .parent");
  $(".child").attr ( "disabled" , true );
}
```

then even i tried adding this

```
  $(this).removeAttr ( "disabled" );
```

but it still disables the all controls

help plz! Thanks

Comment: It sounds to me as if you want radio buttons, not checkboxes.

Comment: No i do want to use the checkboxes. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

**See it here:** http://jsfiddle.net/fEA3Y/

```
var $cbox = $('.child').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $cbox.not(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    } else {
        $cbox.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

If you really need to toggle classes for some reason, you could do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/fEA3Y/2/

```
var $cbox = $('.child').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $(this).toggleClass('child parent');
        $cbox.not(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass('child parent');
        $cbox.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});​
```

Comment: +1. Did not know that you could assign a variable like that and use it within the event.

Comment: Yeah, since the matched set of elements being returned in the jQuery object is needed inside the handler, it's a quick easy way to cache the set instead of re-fetching it every time. It would be the same as doing `var $cbox = $('.child');` on one line, then `$cbox.change( func...` on the next and referencing the same set inside.

Comment: @Jabran - Does this still work? I thought I had noticed that you had Accepted this answer. If there's an issue, let me know. :o)

Comment: I have taken the first box of code and it's working pretty well as I needed. Much thanks for helping out.

Comment: @Jabran - Glad it worked. Remember to "Accept" this answer by clicking the checkbox to the left of it. :o)

Answer (score 0):

Did you do

```
$('.child').removeAttr('disabled')
```

Since you tried it on `.child`, it's kind of hard to tell the context of `this` since you're not posting the full code.

Also, are you there there isn't a `readonly` attribute being set somewhere?